# How to access a table using a string in Lua

Tags: string, lua, coronasdk, lua-table

I am trying to remove `mainMenuButtonGroup1` through `mainMenuButtonGroup6`.

To do this I think I need to do the following: [mainMenuButtonGroup..n] How would I do that?

```
local mainMenuButtonGroup1 = { 1,2 }
local mainMenuButtonGroup2 = { 3,4 }
local mainMenuButtonGroup3 = { 5,6 }
local mainMenuButtonGroup4 = { 7,8 }
local mainMenuButtonGroup5 = { 9,10 }
local mainMenuButtonGroup6 = { 11,12 }

for n = 1, 6 do
      [mainMenuButtonGroup..n] = nil
end
```

Comment: These variables are not global.

Comment: This is a table of display objects in the Corona SDK. In any case, _G would work, I think, if these where global but they are not :(

Comment: Do you need help iterating a table then? Or local variables?

Comment: I need help understanding how to concatenate 2 strings and then use that string to refer to a local table variable. I will then be doing "things" to said table variable. Basically, I don't want to repeat my code 6 times.

Comment: Why do you want to do '"things" to [a] _variable_'? Is it captured in a closure? Your code doesn't show that; And note that variables don't have types in Lua. If you want to do things to a _table value_, that is a different question. Your code doesn't show that either.

Comment: You might be having an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377). Perhaps stating your goal in using the Corona SDK will help.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your comments, I assume this is something like what you want to do, where `t` is the table that you mentioned.

```
for i = 1, 6 do
    local k = 'mainMenuButtonGroup' .. i
    t[k]:removeSelf()
    t[k] = nil
end
```

String concatenation is performed by the `..` double period operator, and table indexing via `.` or `[]`. In this case, you're indexing via `[]` because you're using a variable and not a constant name.

---

**Edit:** Put your similar local variables into a table instead. It makes it far, far easier to iterate as a group. In fact, the only way I know of to iterate locals is through the debug library.

```
local mainMenuButtonGroup = { {1,2}, {3,4}, {5,6}, {7,8}, {9,10} }
table.insert(mainMenuButtonGroup, {11,12})

for i = 1, 6 do
    mainMenuButtonGroup[i] = nil
end
```

Note, however, that setting a numeric index in a table to `nil` does not rearrange the table's numerically indexed values. **I.e.**, you'll leave the table with holes. See [`table.remove`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-table.remove).

Comment: In your example k the the table I want to edit. I altered my question's code for clarity.

Comment: @Gullie667 I've edited my answer in response. Please let me know what you think.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I guess doing it the way I originally wanted to isn't possible in LUA. I'd plus ya up but lack the rep. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the variables are global, they will be in the `_G` table:

```
for n = 1, 6 do
   for i = _G['mainMenuButtonGroup'..n].numChildren, 1, -1 do
      _G['mainMenuButtonGroup'..n][i]:removeSelf()
      _G['mainMenuButtonGroup'..n][i] = nil
   end
end
```

If they are local, you can use [debug.getlocal](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-debug.getlocal), but you will have to loop over all the locals until you find the names you want.  Not ideal, but possible.

Comment: These variables are not global. :(